# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' to type > 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'

Tags: vb.net

I wrote a function that empty all TextBox in my form:

```
Private Sub effacer()
        For Each t As TextBox In Me.Controls
            t.Text = Nothing
        Next
    End Sub
```

But I had this problem :

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' to type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'.

I tried to add this `If TypeOf t Is TextBox Then`  but I had the same problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection contains all controls of the form not only TextBoxes.

Instead you can use [`Enumerable.OfType`](http://Enumerable.OfType) to find and cast all `TextBoxes`:

```
For Each txt As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
    txt.Text = ""
Next
```

If you want to do the same in the "old-school" way:

```
For Each ctrl As Object In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox
        DirectCast(ctrl, TextBox).Text = ""
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

```
For Each t As TextBox In Me.Controls
```

This line right here tries to cast each control to `TextBox`.
You need to change that to `As Control`, or use `Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()` to filter the collection before iterating it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a line of code that will clear all radioButtons from the groupBox, which is attached to the button_click:

```
groupBoxName.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().ToList().ForEach(p => p.Checked = false);
```

Use appropriate changes to adapt it to your needs.