# For each textbox loop

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a foreach loop that checks every TextBox in a panel and changes BackColor if its Text is nothing. I've tried the following:

```
Dim c As TextBox
For Each c In Panel1.Controls
  if c.Text = "" Then
    c.BackColor = Color.LightYellow
  End If
Next
```

but I'm getting the error:

> Unable to cast object of type System.Windows.Forms.Label to type
>   System.windows.forms.textbox

Comment: If you have non-textbox controls in the panel, you need to allow for them.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' to type > 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002128/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-windows-forms-button-to-type-system-wi)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might try something like this instead:

```
  Dim ctrl As Control
  For Each ctrl In Panel1.Controls
  If (ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(TextBox)) Then
      Dim txt As TextBox = CType(ctrl, TextBox)
      txt.BackColor = Color.LightYellow
  End If
```

Comment: You'll want to set the back color back after they type text, which this example fails to do.

Comment: In this particular example, the conditional could be simplified to `If (ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(TextBox)) Then ctrl.BackColor = Color.LightYellow`...

Answer (score 18):

Assuming there are no nested controls:

```
For Each c As TextBox In Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
  If c.Text = String.Empty Then c.BackColor = Color.LightYellow
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this. It'll put the color back when you enter data as well

```
    For Each c As Control In Panel1.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is TextBox Then
            If c.Text = "" Then
                c.BackColor = Color.LightYellow
            Else
                c.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

There is also a different way to do this which involves creating an inherited TextBox control and using that on your form:

```
Public Class TextBoxCompulsory
    Inherits TextBox
    Overrides Property BackColor() As Color
        Get
            If MyBase.Text = "" Then
                Return Color.LightYellow
            Else
                Return DirectCast(System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window, Color)
            End If
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Color)

        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Still throws the same exception, however, the above answer worked which was very similar. Thanks anyways.