# Use a variable to select a label

Tags: vb.net, label

Hear is my code. I uses this code 92 times. What I would like to do is create a sub and call it sending a variable to control a label. So instead of label92.text it would be something like label(labelnum).text.

```
Case 92
                If Label92.Text = "" Then Label92.Text = DataHold(92, 7)
                If Int(Label92.Text) = Int(DataHold(92, 7)) Then
                    Label92.ForeColor = Color.Black
                    Label92.Text = DataHold(92, 7)
                End If
                If Int(Label92.Text) < Int(DataHold(92, 7)) Then
                    Label92.ForeColor = Color.Red
                    Label92.Text = DataHold(92, 7)
                End If
                If Int(Label92.Text) > Int(DataHold(92, 7)) Then
                    Label92.ForeColor = Color.LightBlue
                    Label92.Text = DataHold(92, 7)
                End If
```

Comment: Try to use like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504280/for-each-textbox-loop: For Each c In Panel1.Controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Controls.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```vb
Dim labelNum As Integer = 92
Dim lbl As Label = Controls.Find("Label" & labelNum, True).FirstOrDefault
If lbl IsNot Nothing Then
  'Do something with lbl, which is Label92
End If
```

Side note: That's a lot of labels.  Do consider using other controls, such as a DataGridView or a ListView control, etc. or just paint the information.  Or more to the point, a user using your program is probably not getting a great user experience by looking at that much information on the screen.  Try to reduce it and only show pertinent information.

Comment: error message on Controls.Find("Label" & labelNum, True).FirstOrDefault - FirstOrDefault is not a member or System.Array.

Comment: @user3708128 Reference the LINQ library: `Imports System.Linq`.