# find average of variables

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Full disclosure, I'm working on an assignment for COP2170, but the additional feature isn't apart of the assignment just trying to stretch a little further...

I'm trying to add 5 test scores and output the average of the 5 scores, that part works just fine. In addition I'm trying to add an additional feature that will allow the user to enter less than 5 scores and the program will still output the average of whatever scores were entered.

So this works:

[image]

And this works:

[image]

The problem I'm running into is if the first score is omitted and the rest are filled in, it doesn't work:

[image]

Here's the code I've got so far:

```
Public Class frmTestScoreAverage


    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        Dim decScore1, decScore2, decScore3, decScore4, decScore5 As Double ' decScore1-5 to hold test scores1-5
        Dim decScoreAverage As Double ' to hold test score average
        Dim intDivideBy As Double = 5 ' declare intDivideBy variable with starting value of 5 

        lblStatusLabel.Text = String.Empty 'set error message to empty string

        Try
            ' Read user input convert to double and assign value to variable
            decScore1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtScore1.Text)
            decScore2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtScore2.Text)
            decScore3 = Convert.ToDouble(txtScore3.Text)
            decScore4 = Convert.ToDouble(txtScore4.Text)
            decScore5 = Convert.ToDouble(txtScore5.Text)

            ' Calculate average
            decScoreAverage = (decScore1 + decScore2 + decScore3 + decScore4 + decScore5) / intDivideBy

            'display result
            lblResult.Text = CStr(decScoreAverage)

        Catch
            ' Display error message, asks for all scores
            lblStatusLabel.Text = "Please enter all test scores"

            'Calculate average even without all scores 
            For Each c As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)() 'loop through each textbox in form see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13504361/1947286
                If c.Text = String.Empty Then intDivideBy -= 1 'If text equals empty string, Then decrement intDivideBy
            Next

            'catch divide by zero error
            Try
                'calculate average
                decScoreAverage = (decScore1 + decScore2 + decScore3 + decScore4 + decScore5) / intDivideBy 'add test scores and divide to find average

                'display result
                lblResult.Text = CStr(decScoreAverage)
            Catch
                lblStatusLabel.Text = "Please enter at least one test score"
            End Try

        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

I'm pretty sure the problem has to do with the way I'm finding the average:

```
decScoreAverage = (decScore1 + decScore2 + decScore3 + decScore4 + decScore5) / intDivideBy
```

Is there a way to find the average that will allow for empty variables in any arrangement?

Comment: Look at the status strip at the bottom of the window.  If your own user interface design confuses you then you need to consider changing it.  The ErrorProvider component is helpful.

Comment: @HansPassant The status bar was a requirement of the assignment. I'm trying to show the error message, because I have to, but I'd like it to work in spite of the missing scores.

Comment: Well, then write a little helper Function that takes a String argument and returns 0 if the string is empty, instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: Your project is an example of code driven by exceptions. This is a practice to avoid. Use TryParse to verify the inputs and if statements to execute code only when you are in an acceptable situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that Convert.ToDouble(txtBox.text) (with empty string, will make Convert throw an Exception.

Add a validation that the string isn't empty or use TryParse to see if the Textbox value is parseable to a number.

Either

```
If not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBox.Text) then
   Convert.ToDouble(txtBox.text)
```

Or

```
 dim value as Double
 if Double.TryParse(txtBox.Text, value) then
     avg += value
```

When the first one is empty, it goes to the Catch part of the code, then you try to calculate the avg, but the values of the Txtbox are not assigned to the declarations you made, so when it tries to do the average

```
    decScore1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtScore1.Text) // Exception here to Catch
    decScore2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtScore2.Text) // Not evaluated
    decScore3 = Convert.ToDouble(txtScore3.Text) // Not evaluated
    decScore4 = Convert.ToDouble(txtScore4.Text) // Not evaluated
    decScore5 = Convert.ToDouble(txtScore5.Text) // Not evaluated
```

Theses do not have any value, in return this doesn't do what you want

```
decScoreAverage = (decScore1 + decScore2 + decScore3 + decScore4 + decScore5) / intDivideBy
```

**UPDATE**
(Vb code not tested)

```
Function GetTextValue(dim score as string) as Double
    dim value as Double = 0

    if (Double.TryParse(score, value)) 
        return value
    else
        return value

End Function
```

This

```
decScore1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtScore1.Text)
```

Becomes

```
decScore1 = GetTextValue(txtScore1.Text)
```

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you're saying. It looks like I would need a if statement or TryParse for each variable, is there a way to DRY it out?

Comment: Convert.ToDouble(string.Empty) will throw a FormatException

Comment: Sorry I'm painfully new to VB, I'm guessing that's a no?

Comment: Check Updated answer, that will help you out, should fix the problem you are having, when Textbox are empty they are converted to 0

Comment: If I have a web question, I'll know who to contact ;) Nice Home Page

Comment: My site needs a lot of work... The shoemakers children go barefoot if you get my meaning. Feel free to hit me up.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you store reference to each textbox in an array. You'll see why at the end of this example.

```
Public Class frmTestScoreAverage

    Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponent()
        Me.boxes = {Me.txtScore1, Me.txtScore2, Me.txtScore3, Me.txtScore4, Me.txtScore5}
    End Sub

    Private boxes As TextBox()
```

The common way to [validate user input in winforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is to handle the [Validating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event, usually combined with the [error provider class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as mentioned by [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant).

```
    Private Sub HandleScoreValidating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles txtScore1.Validating, txtScore2.Validating, txtScore3.Validating, txtScore4.Validating, txtScore5.Validating
        With DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
            If ((Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(.Text)) AndAlso (Not Double.TryParse(.Text, 0.0R))) Then
                e.Cancel = True
                'Alert or set error provider:
                'Me.ErrorProvider1.SetError(DirectCast(sender, Control), "Not double")
            Else
                e.Cancel = False
                'Clear error provider:
                'Me.ErrorProvider1.Clear()
            End If
        End With
    End Sub
```

Now, back to the textbox array. Create a new list of double and iterate the textbox array. If the text isn't empty, parse and add the value to the list. At the end, use the [Average](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) extension method to get the average value.

```
    Private Sub HandleCalculate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

        Dim values As New List(Of Double)

        For Each box As TextBox In Me.boxes
            If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(box.Text)) Then
                values.Add(Double.Parse(box.Text))
           'Else
            '    values.Add(0.0R)
            End If
        Next

        Dim average As Double = values.Average()

        '....

    End Sub

End Class
```