# Loop through textboxes in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I remember in vb6 you were able to create the array of textboxes.

```
Textbox1(0), Textbox1(1) ..... ,
```

But in vb.net you can't create array ? So if you have code like this . Is it possible set it into for loop ?

```
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""
        TextBox3.Text = ""
        TextBox4.Text = ""
        TextBox5.Text = ""
        TextBox6.Text = ""
        TextBox7.Text = ""
        TextBox8.Text = ""
        TextBox9.Text = ""
        TextBox10.Text = ""
        TextBox11.Text = ""
        TextBox12.Text = ""
        TextBox13.Text = ""
        TextBox14.Text = ""
        TextBox15.Text = ""
```

Comment: You _could_ try searching next time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504280/for-each-textbox-loop

Comment: Also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299435/how-to-create-control-arrays-in-vb-net), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199521/vb-net-iterating-through-controls-in-a-container-object), etc...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the TextBox controls are just on the main form, then you can loop through them:

```
For Each tb As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
  tb.Text = String.Empty
Next
```

If they are in a panel, then replace the `Me` keyword with the name of the panel.

Comment: Is `OfType` recursive? Or does it just get direct children?

Comment: @jwatts1980 Not recursive — it's just a filter.

Comment: @jwatts1980:- Its not recursive!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a List and loop through it:

```
Dim boxes As New List(Of TextBox)() From { _
    TextBox1, _
    TextBox2 _
}
boxes.Add(TextBox3)

For Each tb As TextBox In boxes
    tb.Text = ""
Next
```

If you have a Form with TextBox controls down inside other controls such as a Panel, or GroupBox, you can try to use a recursive function like this to get them all. (This is basically a [C# to VB conversion](http://converter.telerik.com/) of the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4630450/579148))

```
Private Function GetTextBoxes(root As Control) As IEnumerable(Of TextBox)
    Dim container = TryCast(root, ContainerControl)
    If container IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each c As Control In container.Controls
            For Each i As Control In GetTextBoxes(c)
                Yield i
            Next
        Next
    End If
End Function
```

To create a list from your main form:

```
Dim allBoxes As List(Of TextBox) = GetTextBoxes(Me).ToList()
```

Answer (score 2):

For reference, you CAN create an Array of TextBox objects, in the following manner:

`Dim tbArray() As TextBox = New TextBox() {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3}`

Or, declare the array and loop through the TextBox controls to add them to it. However, the `List(Of TextBox)` approach will work just fine if you need to keep a collection of them, or simply looping through the TextBox controls on the form if you just need to set the properties in one sub or function.