# Display for loop values in an array or list of textboxes

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list

I have a very simple for loop statement as shown below. How to display each value to a corresponding textbox using an array or list? In my loop I have 6 indexes and I have also 6 textboxes, which means index 0 will be displayed in txtbox1, index 1 will be displayed in txtbox2 so on and so forth.

```
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 5
       ' TextBox Here
    Next
```

Comment: *List* is used if you want to add remove sort and other stuff dynamically. If your number of textboxes are fixed and unchanged then *array* is ok.

Comment: Can you show me some examples, please.

Comment: [Loop through textboxes in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604633/loop-through-textboxes-in-vb-net). I think it can be marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all text boxes, you want to assign value from an array, are child control of `Form`. If text box name starts from `txtBox0` then remove `i+1` from the below code.

```
    Dim arr() As String = {"aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee"}

    Dim txtBox As TextBox
    Dim ctrlName As String
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To 5
        ' TextBox Here
        ctrlName = "txtbox" + (i + 1).ToString
        Try
            txtBox = CType(Me.Controls(ctrlName), TextBox)
            If Not txtBox Is Nothing Then
                txtBox.Text = arr(i)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            'ignore or raise error
        End Try
    Next
```